# Facebook PHP SDK (v.3.2.1) Line Brake Problems, while posting an event

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, line-breaks

I've been working with Facebook PHP SDK (v.3.2.1) to post events on a fan page. But I have some trouble passing line brakes in the array field, especially on the description field.

Since the event has to be saved on mysql for website purpose's i'm using \n but it seems to fail

```
$return = $facebook->api('/PAGE/events', 'POST', array(
            'name' => $_POST['title'],
            'description' => $_POST['description'],
            'location' => $_POST['location'],
            'start_time' =>  $_POST['year'].'-'.$_POST['month'].'-'.$_POST['day'].'T'.$_POST['hour'].':'.$_POST['minute'].':00-0800',
            'privacy_type' => 'SECRET'
         ));
```

But `\n` are printed on the event, i tryed to **nl2br** strings but again, `<br>` are printed on the fb event.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing array in line 1.try this

```
$return = $facebook->api('/PAGE/events/', 'POST', array(
            'name' => $_POST['title'],
            'description' => $_POST['description'],
            'location' => $_POST['location'],
            'start_time' =>  $_POST['year'].'-'.$_POST['month'].'-'.$_POST['day'].'T'.$_POST['hour'].':'.$_POST['minute'].':00-0800',
            'privacy_type' => 'SECRET'
         ));
```

Comment: okay yes thank you!!, sorry about that... still that's not my real problem

Comment: It was a problem with "/PAGE/events" it should be "/PAGE/events/" with a slash at the end brrrrrrrrr

Comment: ok,I just notice that,I'm missing slash('/') there I have corrected it.